# How to handle primary key violation when updating composite keys

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following table in SQL Server, which keeps track of the users in a group, or what groups does a user belong to. Many-Many relationship.

```
CREATE TABLE a_group_user(
    user_id INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES dbo.appuser(user_id),
    group_id INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES dbo.usergroup(group_id),
    PRIMARY KEY(user_id, group_id)
);
```

A user can belong to multiple groups. For example:

```
user_id | group_id
------------------
1       |   1
1       |   3
2       |   3
```

In my business logic, I want to be able to add one group to another group. For this, I wrote a simple query which adds group 3 users to group 1 (**Edit**: group 3 should be emptied in the process):

```
UPDATE dbo.a_group_user
SET group_id = 1
WHERE group_id = 3
```

However, this gives me a primary key constraint violation error as expected, since changing the group_id to 1 for user_id of 1 with an existing group_id of 3 will result in duplicate records.

The error:

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK__a_group___A4E94E55A054C364'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.a_group_user'. The duplicate key value is (1, 1).

Please help me out

Comment: Your query is not `adds group 3 users to group 1`. Rather It is changing `group 3 users to group 1`. You will need to use `INSERT`  query and not `UPDATE`

Comment: If you want to add group-3 users to group 1, shouldn't this be an insert? Or shall the group 3 be emptied in the same process?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner I have edited the question for clarification. Thank you for pointing out.

Comment: @Squirrel Post has been edited with changes. Thank you!

Comment: Okay, so it is not only an update of rows that you want, because with your sample data of three rows, you want to end up with only two. Does one of the answers work for you?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Yes. I marked the answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to delete the record from this table if user exists in both the groups and then update `group_id` 3 to 1 for all.
You need to use multiple queries as follows:

```
DELETE U
FROM dbo.a_group_user U
WHERE U.group_id = 1
AND EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM dbo.a_group_user UU 
    WHERE UU.group_id = 3
    AND uu.user_id = u.user_id
);

UPDATE dbo.a_group_user SET
    group_id = 1
WHERE group_id = 3;
```

Comment: You have to add the alias U after the DELETE keyword as well. (DELETE U FROM dbo.a_group_user U WHERE ...)

Answer (score -1):

You need to delete the existing group memberships and then insert the new group memberships. Here's an example:

Step 1: Delete existing group memberships for the specified users and group

```
DELETE
FROM dbo.a_group_user
WHERE user_id IN (
    SELECT user_id
    FROM dbo.a_group_user 
    WHERE group_id = 3
)
AND group_id = 1;
```

Step 2: Insert new group memberships

```
INSERT INTO dbo.a_group_user (user_id, group_id)
SELECT user_id, 1
FROM dbo.a_group_user
WHERE group_id = 3;
```